# php GET method with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, methods, get

i'm new in php,
i want to obtain these results using $_GET and arrays:

```
http://127.0.0.1/get.php?id=0 i want to display to me example0
http://127.0.0.1/get.php?id=1 i want to display to me example0
http://127.0.0.1/get.php?id=2 i want to display to me example0
http://127.0.0.1/get.php?id=3 i want to display to me example0
```

i tried this:

```
<?php
$names=array('example0','example1','example2','example3');
echo $_GET[names];
?>
```

and doesn't work !

Comment: um? no idea what you are asking

Comment: How are you passing that array in the URL?

Comment: Do you want to use an array to create a URL or would you like to accept an array from a get parameter?

Answer (score 2):

This is less grunt work and more elegant:

```
$names=array('example0','example1','example2','example3');

$index = $_GET['id'];
echo $names[$index];
```

You should check if the index exists in a more realistic situation:

```
$names=array('example0','example1','example2','example3');

$index = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($names[$index])){//Check if index exists
    echo $names[$index];
}
```

This way you don't have to change code when your array changes!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 0){
  ...
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == 1){
  ...
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == 2){
  ...
} elseif ($_GET['id'] == 3){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh haha that's what they are asking!